# How can I get record which has same value in two column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In this table I have 3 column firstname lastname and age. In this table there are some duplicate record. For example In two record, firstname and lastname are same only age different. I want to get which records like that with SQL query. How can I get records which has same first name and same last name.

Sample data

[image: Sample Table]

I want to get all record which has john as first name and has doe as lastname.

Comment: Select * from Table where FirstName='john' and LastName='doe';

Comment: @sojin no john doe is only sample. In that table there are many records which has same first name and last name. I want to get all same record not only john doe.

Comment: `I want to get all record which has john as first name and has doe as lastname`. If that's not what you want, don't write it into your question.

Comment: Is the real issue here about finding "duplicates"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query which gives you all records which have same name but diff or same age

```
Select *, 
   rn =dense_rank() 
        over (partition by firstname, lastname order by age asc) 
from yourtable
```

This gives same rank(rn column) value for all records with same name. Now if you need all records which have same name from the table.

```
select * from 
(
    Select *, 
       rn =dense_rank() 
            over (partition by firstname, lastname order by age asc) 
    from yourtable
) T
where firstname =@firstname and lastname =@lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query and `count` function here

Assuming table name is `users`

```
select * from users 
    where (select count(id) from users as nested_users 
            where nested_users.FirstName=users.FirstName 
            and nested_users.LastName=users.LastName) > 1;
```

`nested_users` is an alias

Comment: no john doe is only sample. In that table there are many records which has same first name and last name. I want to get all same records not only john doe.

Comment: @Can Okay I got your question. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way which is quite "natural" to read is to ask, "for all rows, is there another row (ie, a row with a different id) that has the same first and last name":

```sql
select t.id, t.firstName, t.lastName, t.age
from   MyTable t
where  exists  
       (
          select *
          from   MyTable
          where  firstName = t.firstName
                 and lastName = t.lastName
                 and id != t.id
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

*This query will return data that has duplicates and show the total duplicates*

Answer (score 0):

```
select user1.*     
         from User user1 , User user2
             where user1.firstName = user2.firstName 
                   and user1.lastName = user2.lastName 
                   and user1.id != user2.id
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29757357)

Comment: @krystanhonour: What makes you think this is a new question?